# how to read data that is stored with array in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

i stored data by using multiple checkbox in mysql. i want to show this stored data without include comma by using array. but, it is shown as the array was count comma

`index.php`

```php
    include('config.php');
    $results = array();
    $sql = "select * from assign1 where id='1'";

    $run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
        $results[] = $row['assign'];   ?> 

<p><?php print_r($results) ?></p>

<?php echo $results[0][0] ."".$results[0][2]."". $results[0][4] ?>

    <?php   } ?>
```

In **mysql**,

[image]

In **output**, i stored no 11, but array is only show 1.

> output : 691

Comment: Use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to "explode" the string by `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to `explode()` function:

```
$results[] = explode(',', $row['assign']);

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result.'/n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use explode() to convert from string to array

```
$a = "1,2,3";
$d = explode(',',$a);
print_r($d);
```